# resolving onion domains partially fails

Tags: onion-routing, dns, transparent-proxy, log

Init:

1. For user `anonymous` configured [transpared proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#LocalRedirectionThroughTor).
2. Wireshark sniffing `lo`...
3. Trying to use *console network-tools* torified.

> anonymous@kali:/tmp$ time strace -s6000 -t -f dig facebookcorewwwi.onion > dig.strace 2>&1

- pastebin.com/it1tk8jQ   - **visible in wireshark.**

> anonymous@kali:/tmp$ time strace -s6000 -t -f host facebookcorewwwi.onion > host.strace 2>&1

- pastebin.com/EgWWsM55 - **not visible.**

> anonymous@kali:/tmp$ time strace -s6000 -t -f wget -O -
>   facebookcorewwwi.onion > wget.strace 2>&1

- pastebin.com/cB1dSHDd - not visible. (Optional, just for being)

Means, only `dig` given valid IP-Address from `VirtualAddrNetwork` from `torrc`:

```
VirtualAddrNetwork 172.16.0.0/12 # private network 10.x.x.x is not available
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
```

Other tools hanged. Retried to reconnect to DNS-servers couple of times, thereafter broke with `connection timed out; no servers could be reached` or something like that.

However, I did not seen anything in Wireshark. Only `dig` was highlighted with specified DNS request redirected by `iptables` to loop-back interface 53 port.

What is strange, both `dig` and `host` are using the **same functions** with the **same flags**:

dig:

```
[pid 10713] 06:41:58 sendmsg(20, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, 
sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.99.248.2")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"<\331\1 
\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\20facebookcorewwwi\5onion\0\0\1\0\1\0\0)\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 51}],
msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 51
```

host:

```
[pid 10394] 06:41:38 sendmsg(20, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, 
sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.99.248.2")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"9\307\1
\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\20facebookcorewwwi\5onion\0\0\1\0\1", 40}],
msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0 <unfinished ...>
```

Only payloads are little bit different.

My question is about this pastebined logs: **Where is this place in log which** is wrong for `host` and right for `dig`???? Because I'm not seeing anything. `bind`, `sendmsg`, `socket`, etc - everything seems are equivalent.

Why does `dig` working, resolving onion domain into ip address but `host`, `wget`, `nslookup`, `chromium`... and other doesn't? ***Most of mysterium with onion domains only.*** Every other domains are resolving successfully and highlighted on `lo` side in Wireshark successfully by any *network-tool* or even `chromium`...

Probably, it is because `dig` is most robust tool to resolve ip addr, then what is wrong with other? Why are they not so smart?

Comment: Likely entirely unrelated to `dig` or `host`, since both work under normal circumstances. Review the rest of your setup, at a guess I'd suspect `iptables` is setup wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a standard setup with local DNS server located on your very PC - it caches the response locally inside the server, so no second request is made. If you have more questions - feel free to ask!

Comment: You are right! After I have changed /etc/resolv.conf to `nameserver 127.0.0.1` - everything is fine for onion domains.  Thx.