# Why does TransparentProxy working with `nameserver 127.0.0.1` but doesn't working with iptables redirects?

Tags: onion-routing, dns, transparent-proxy

This my second question is a continuation of my [first one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12476/resolving-onion-domains-partially-fails).

Setup is default Kali 2 and configured `anonymous` user from [TransparentProxy manual](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#LocalRedirectionThroughTo) on it.

While I'm using `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf` - everything is fine. All *console network-tools* like `dig`, `nslookup`, `host`, etc, are working normally with resolving ***.onion** domains into IP addresses.

But, If `dhclient` rewriting `/etc/resolv.conf` with my local DNS-servers, this idyll disappearing...

As you can read from my first question, I'm catching DNS-requests with Wireshark on `lo`-interface. `dig` to ***.onion** domains - redirected to `lo` by iptablres well, but other *network-tools* - not.

Why does iptables redirect works with every other domains, but does not works with ***.onion** and requires `nameserver 127.0.0.1`?

Or

My question may sounds like: Why does `nameserver 127.0.0.1` exists in TransparentProxy configuration, if iptables already configured to redirect every DNS-request to any IP-address to `loop-back`:53?

**EDIT:** Specially for @canonizing ironize:

```
$IPT -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
$IPT -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
$IPT -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m tcp --dport 9040 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t filter -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -j REJECT
```

Anyway, I can not find difference between ***.onion** domains and other... And how does this difference depend on `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Are you sure your `iptables` rules are correct for your setup? Note that those on the wiki are explicitly marked as an example and come with a set of assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

@canonizing ironize was right. It is my Setup. My mistake.

I've used suricata IDS in inline mode with default `drop` policy for almost every available rule.

So, rule number 2014939:

```
emerging-policy.rules:#drop udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET POLICY DNS Query
for TOR Hidden Domain .onion Accessible Via TOR"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|05|onion|00|"; fast_pattern; distance:0; 
reference:url,en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion; classtype:policy-violation; 
sid:2014939; rev:1;
```

Anyway, it is interesting, because `dig`'s request was working:

```
<\331\1 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\20facebookcorewwwi\5onion\0\0\1\0\1\0\0)\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
```

And `host`'s request was not:

```
9\307\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\20facebookcorewwwi\5onion\0\0\1\0\1
```

It is this place in rule:

```
content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00|"; 
depth:10; 
offset:2; 
content:"|05|onion|00|"; 
fast_pattern; distance:0;
```

Probably, `dig` as a modern tool using more robust query `01000001` and it does not match old version of emerging-policy rules.

Thanx everybody. I dive. Ai ai, skipper!

Answer (score 1):

My good advice to you - use local instance of Bind and route all DNS queries through it. I'm using it quite for a long time - no problems so far. And - dhclient will not vandalize resolv conf after this:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```